# HTTP 500 Internal Server Error using jersey

Tags: java, jersey

i copied this code but it gives Error 500 internal server error.  his code is running flawless.
What to do ?

Alien.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Alien {


private String name;
private int points;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}
public void setPoints(int points) {
    this.points = points;
}

}
```

AlienResources.java

```
@Path("aliens")
public class AlienResources {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Alien getAlien(){
    System.out.println("getAlien Called.....");     // this is printing fine in console
    Alien a = new Alien();
    a.setName("manjit");
    a.setPoints(90);
    return a;
}
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam there is no error in console.. but there is a error showing in marker Description Resource Path Location Type
JAX-RS (REST Web Services) 2.1 can not be installed : One or more constraints have not been satisfied. demorest  line 1 Maven Java EE Configuration Problem

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam and a error is showing in Java Resource Folder.